# Puedo poner elementos creados en JS dentro de svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, plugin

Estoy creando un Plugin para grafana, con @grafana/toolkit y quiero agregar un radar de chart.js dentro de un codigo svg. Al llamar a mi componente creado si lo intento graficar dentro del codigo svg no se me grafica, pero al momento de ponerlo fuer del  si se me grafica pero fuera de los otros elementos y quiero que este dentro junto a los demas elementos svg

```
<svg
        id="svg8"
        viewBox="0 0 507.99999 211.66667"
        height={'100%'}
        width={'100%'}
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        //{...props}
      >
      <varios elementos svg>
      //Aqui quiero añadir mi elemento js(radar.js)
      <Radar/> // **Quiero llamarlo dentro para que se grafique en un espacio dentro del svg pero no se me gráfica **
      </svg>
<Radar/> // **si lo llamo desde afuera si se gráfica y se coloca fuera del svg**
```

Comment: ¿Con *radar.js* te refieres a [este paquete NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radar.js)? Que funcione o no depende de qué te genere el script al que haces referencia (que desconozco cuál es, parece no ser estándar) dentro del DOM del documento. Si éste crea un elemento SVG adicional, entonces anidarlo no te va a funcionar, sin embargo sí que podrías obtener su contenido y pegarlo dentro del otro SVG.